# Visual Studio 2013 SDKDDKVer.h and related errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

So I tried installing visual studio 2013 and building the default console application, and it gave me:

```
error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'SDKDDKVer.h': No such file or directory
```

So after about 7 hours, including installing VS on a brand new Windows 7 SP1 install on a virtual machine to see if that solved the problem (it did not), I found this solution:

In the project properties page,
set configuration properties->vc++ directories to 
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Include"

set library directories to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Lib

and copy RC.Exe and RcDll.Dll from C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Bin to C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin

To my utter amazement, this actually worked!  It now builds the default console program.  However it is *still* giving me:

```
warning MSB8003: Could not find WindowsSDKDir variable from the registry.  
TargetFrameworkVersion or PlatformToolset may be set to an invalid version number.
```

And to my great irritation, I have to set these include/lib paths for *every* project.

So, here are my questions:

1) Is this the normal procedure?! - ANSWER: No.

2) If not, why am I (and lots of others, it seems) getting these problems? -ANSWER: Probably either (i) Didn't have Windows SDK 8.1 installed and/or (ii) Not online during install of visual studio.

3) Should I care about the aforementioned "warning MSB8003" or just ignore it?  It seems to work now, after all...ANSWER: Oh dear, the above method really DOESN'T fix the problem properly.

4) How can I set the lib/include vc++ directories *permanently* for every project?  Or is this not possible? ANSWER: You can, but you don't have to once you have the SDK 8.1 installed.

That's it I guess, thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: Are you trying to build a pre VS 2013 solution?  Or, a brand new solution?

Comment: The entire *system* was brand new on the VM.  Yes, it was brand spanking shiny new...

Comment: You may some other issues.  I just created a new console app that does nothing and it built without problems.  Are you modifying the sample in any way?

Comment: Not one character was altered.  I think this is actually a problem with *offline* install of VS2013.  Like, maybe I need the 8.1 SDK or something...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downloading and installing the Windows 8.1 SDK (on a machine that is never online, grr...) solved all problems with no further action necessary.  Probably the problem was caused by not being online during install of visual studio.  I wonder why the VS 2013 installer doesn't come up with an explicit message before VS is installed.  Something like : *"EMERGENCY WARNING!!!  YOU ARE NOT ONLINE!!! NOTHING WILL WORK PROPERLY!!! YOU ABSOLUTELY MUST INSTALL WINDOWS SDK 8.1 AT SOME POINT BEFORE ANYTHING WILL WORK!!!! I'M NOT KIDDING!!! REALLY!!!"*

Something like that anyway....Oh, and this is obviously the best answer, which I will mark as such if I'm allowed to...

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem, I solved it by defining an environment variable, restart visual studio 2013

> Add an environment variable **`"WindowsSDKDir"`** with `value="path to the microsoft sdk"`

e.g. in my case

```
WindowsSDKDir=C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A
```

Answer (score 1):

I just had this exact problem. After hours and hours in trying to find the problem by looking at different paths and trying to change them, uninstalling all MS products and reinstalling them etc. without any success, I found the solution to be to open the file C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\MSBuild\v4.0\Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user.props and changing

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <IncludePath>$(VCInstallDir)include;$(VCInstallDir)atlmfc\include;$(WindowsSdkDir)include;$(FrameworkSDKDir)\include;C:\Program Files (x86)\BCGSoft\BCGControlBarPro\BCGCBPro;C:\Program Files (x86)\BCGSoft\BCGControlBarPro\BCGCBPro</IncludePath>
  <LibraryPath>$(VCInstallDir)lib;$(VCInstallDir)atlmfc\lib;$(WindowsSdkDir)lib;$(FrameworkSDKDir)\lib;C:\Program Files (x86)\BCGSoft\BCGControlBarPro\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\BCGSoft\BCGControlBarPro\bin</LibraryPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

to

```
<PropertyGroup />
```

I don't know how this problem arose, but I found the solution by copying the file from my colleague's machine where it all worked fine. The problem might be caused to recent install and uninstall of BCGControlBarPro...